# Deleting multiple data for a given set of IDs in Stored Procedures MYSQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am trying to write a stored procedure for deleting data from 160+ tables.
There are 1.6 million candidate_ids and the corresponding data to be deleted from all these 160 tables. Executing line by line for a single ID is consuming a lot of time as using below procedure. Is there a way I can increase the efficiency of procedure by using bulk data of say 5000 ids at once and delete. How can I achieve it?

Below is the procedure:

```
SP:BEGIN

DECLARE non_deleted_count INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE startRow INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE startCandidateId INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE startPaymentId INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE endRow INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE startPurgeCandidateId INT UNSIGNED;
DECLARE endPurgeCandidateId INT UNSIGNED;

SELECT COUNT(*) 
INTO non_deleted_count
FROM purgeCandidateIDList
WHERE ISNULL(deleted_flag);

if non_deleted_count > 0 then
    SELECT COALESCE(MAX(purge_candidate_id),0)+1
    INTO startRow
    FROM purgeCandidateIDList 
    WHERE deleted_flag = 1;

    SELECT MAX(purge_candidate_id)
    INTO endRow
    FROM purgeCandidateIDList;
else 
    LEAVE SP;
end if;

while startRow <= endRow
DO
    SELECT candidate_id
    INTO startCandidateId
    FROM purgeCandidateIDList 
    WHERE purge_candidate_id = startRow;

    
    DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE candidate_id = startCandidateId;
    ....
    ....
    160 tables...
    
    UPDATE purgeCandidateIDList SET deleted_flag = 1 WHERE candidate_id = startCandidateId;
    
    SET startRow = startRow + 1;
   END WHILE;

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting row by row, using the `IN` operator in your delete statement.

```
DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE candidate_id IN (SELECT candidate_id FROM purgeCandidateIDList);
```